# Can't start a Background service in onCreate of an Activity

Tags: android, android-service

In my app, I need to keep a background service alive throughout the duration of the app. So, I start the background service in `onCreate` method. But for some reason, I am getting this on some devices:

```
android.app.BackgroundServiceStartNotAllowedException

Exception java.lang.RuntimeException:
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4169)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4325)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2574)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8757)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:571)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1067)
Caused by android.app.BackgroundServiceStartNotAllowedException:
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1981)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startService (ContextImpl.java:1927)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:834)
  at org.app.android.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:55)
```

I am aware that you are not allowed to start a BackgroundService when the app is in background, but if I'm in onCreate doesn't that mean, I am in foreground or is it too soon to call it foreground?

The code in question:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Intent docSaverServiceIntent = new Intent(this, DocSaverService.class);


        startService(docSaverServiceIntent); // <------ the crash happens here
    }
```

Comment: no the activity  can be in the background even if `created`

Comment: "I need to keep a background service alive throughout the duration of the app" -- what do you mean by "the duration of the app"? Beyond that, please provide a [mcve] showing the code that leads to that stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare while the app is in Foreground. I have the stripped down version of how I start the service and where it crashes.

Comment: @kingston so it means, `onCreate` is not a method where we have Foreground guarantee?

Comment: "while the app is in Foreground" -- the point of a service is to do work when your app is **not** in the foreground. Why do you think that you need one when your app **is** in the foreground?

Comment: @CommonsWare I need it as a workaround. I actually use a Foreground service to run a routine to save some state (which is from C++), and this saving can be slow, so I need to make sure that the app process gets to live a few minutes beyond the Activity lifetime. So, on some devices for some reason I can't start a ForegroundService when I am in onPause (even though docs say it is allowed), so as a workaround, I have a background service which is alive and it is only invoked when the app is paused or killed and it lives for a few seconds, before it finishes.

Comment: "so I need to make sure that the app process gets to live a few minutes beyond the Activity lifetime" -- that feels like a better role for `WorkManager`. "I am in foreground or is it too soon to call it foreground?" -- try `onResume()` or `onStart()`. Technically, I don't know that you're in the foreground until one of those two lifecycle events.

Comment: I did try WorkManager, but it doesn't guarantee that the app process (as in the linux proc) survives, so I can't rely on it, I think what it guarantees is the work is done (but then work will only be done if the proc is alive).. Let me give it a shot to `onResume` to see if it reduces the # of exceptions. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @codeconscious why don't you try to start the service normally in onCreate and move it to the foreground when the lifecycle is in the Started state?

Comment: @CommonsWare am I mistaken or it is right to start a service in the foreground when the app is in the foreground to be sure that it will already be in the foreground if you move the app to the background? With the latest version of Android you can't move the service to the foreground if the app is already in the background. Right?

Comment: @kingston: "it is right to start a service in the foreground when the app is in the foreground to be sure that it will already be in the foreground if you move the app to the background?" -- I would do that for ongoing work (e.g., media playback).